# OpenGL Memory allocation problems for drawing

Tags: android

I'm very new to Android and I'm writing my first app which consists of drawing STL data (a bunch of triangles).
For a small number of triangles (~ 4000), my app works great. But as soon as I try to load large data (~ 100000 triangles), I get memory allocation problems. Here is basically what I do:

I am using a GLSurfaceView for my rendering

a) I read in my data, creating a list of triangles (3 * X/Y/Z and a normal vector for each triangle)
b) I create ByteBuffers using allocateDirect() for the vertex data, the normals and the indices.
c) I add the data into the ByteBuffers
d) I call glVertexPointer, glNormalPointer and I assign the bytebuffers
e) I call glDrawElements() using the indexBuffer

As soon as I try to allocate around 10MB by calling allocateDirect(), my application crashes. I tried to calll allocate() instead, which works, but then the glVertexPointer method crashes (even for a small number of triangles)

Am I doing something wrong?

Also, do I have to call glVertexPointer, glNormalPointer every time I redraw or is it enough to call it in the surfaceChanged method?

Thanks a lot,

Mark

Answer (score 1):

You should only create the VBOs once.  After that if you need to load new data into them you do it in local arrays, and then load it in to the VBOs all at once using a "put" call.

The largest type that you can use for the index VBO is "short", so you can only draw 64k vertexes at a time.  If you are drawing 100k vertexes, you will have to do it in two passes.

Edit: regarding your memory limitations, find out what the heap limit is for your device.  The heap limit can be 16, 24, 32, or 48 MB.  You can use the "android:largeHeap="true"" option to greatly increase the limits, but I'm not sure if that option is available for pre-Honeycomb versions of Android or not.

Comment: Of course, that makes sense with the shorts. Thanks! So what happens if I try to use 32 bit integers as indices? I'll try that later on. But 64k would be quite limiting, now I have to think about level of detail to keep the number of vertices below 64k. Do you know of an "easy" way of doing this? Thanks!

Comment: @Mark You can't, because in the glDrawElements call (I'm assuming that's what you're using), you have to indicate what type your indices are, and Android's OpenGL ES (may be an OpenGL ES thing in general) does not allow anything bigger than GL_UNSIGNED_SHORT.  Regular OpenGL does, on the other hand, support unsigned ints.

Comment: Hi Jim, I've done a few more tests today and it seems this is more a generic memory limit than anything else. I split my vertex data into multiple opengl vertex arrays (each of them being limited to 64k triangles) and still I had problems allocating the memory. The more memory I allocate before (using lists etc...), the less memory I have available for my buffers. All in all I'm trying to allocate around 10 MB of RAM and no-can-do.

Comment: @Mark, Did you try the "largeHeap" option in your AndroidManifest?

Comment: Hi Jim, I was able to render my 100k vertices without having to change the RAM limitation (largeHeap option), by checking for redundant vertices. And it seems around 100k vertices is also the performance edge for the device. I get around 10 fps rotating the scene so I now have a feeling of what is possible. Thanks again for your help!!

Comment: So the quest continues. I was using vertex arrays before and now I've changed my code to use VBOs. Rotating the scene with 100k vertices is now smooth as silk so it's time to load a bigger model...

Answer (score 0):

I'm not expert with 3D rendering, but 10MB of vertex data strikes me as quite a lot, especially for a mobile application, so I'm not surprised you're encountering memory allocation issues! Even if they did successfully get allocated, you'd likely find it unusable due to poor performance.

Does the entire scene really need to be in video memory all the time? You may want to explore techniques to cull vertices that are far away from the camera and only upload/draw what is necessary.

Comment: Hi Dave,I'm programming for a tablet that has 1GB of RAM, so 10MB of vertex data should not be limiting. I will worry about performance when it comes up, first it has to run...